# Ruby and gems installation

Tags: ruby, bundle

I have ruby project and I installed all gems using 'bundle install'. Gems was installed in ./vendor/bundle. But I use ruby installed by rvm in another directory and when I try to do something (some command) It is looking for gems in rvm directory. How to install all gems in rvm directory?

Edit:
I installed all gems but when I tried to user simple ruby -T I get:

```
/home/arkency/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rake' (>= 0) among 1 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /home/arkency/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
from /home/arkency/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
from /home/arkency/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
from /home/arkency/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/arkency/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

My gem list contain only:

```
gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.6.2)
```

Comment: You can just do `rvmsudo bundle install`

Comment: try `bundle install --system`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, bundler installs gems to the system gem store. However, it has an optional configuration setting to install gems into another directory (in your case `vendor/bundle`). These gems are then only available in the specific bundler context.

You can force bundler to install the gems into the system gem store by running

```
bundle install --system
```

thus making them available to your global ruby installation.

This is necessary as bundler remembers certain options (e.g. the path where to install gems to) in the `.bundle` directory besides your `Gemfile`.